# phpexcel remove the middle border line between 2 cells?

Tags: php, phpexcel

in phpexcel how do i remove the middle border line between 2 cells?

like this pic: [image: pic]

it currently shows as: [image]

this is my current code:

```
    $styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOUBLE
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("G".$rownum.":H".$rownum)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I agree that your method works @Dagon I feel it's a little messy, instead I would recommend using the 'outline' method.  Like so

```
'borders' => array(
   'outline' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOUBLE
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

specify each side separately for the cells

```
 'borders' => array(
    'left' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOUBLE,
    ),
    'right' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOUBLE,
    ),
    'bottom' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOUBLE,
    ),
    'top' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOUBLE,
    ),
```

one cell will have right 'none' one with have left 'none'

Comment: You mean 'right' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE,
    )